Render JPEG stored in S3 Bucket, without saving image
I have an R Shiny app where I save images from an S3 bucket (after checking if they exist) and then render them using the following code. The 'image1.jpeg' in this example changes based on user input and gets overwritten quite a bit during the course of using the app. Instead of saving the image in order to render, I wanted to see if it was possible to just read into memory and render?
I know the aws.s3 package has an s3_readusing() function which I think I could utilize, but I am not sure how to tie this into renderImage() since the first parameter of the list (src) seems to require a path to an image?
Simplified Example Code:
# this is part of a larger observeEvent(), where image1.jpeg is changing based on user input
if(aws.s3::object_exists(key1, bucket = bucket_name) == TRUE){
   aws.s3::save_object(key1, bucket_name, file = "images/image1.jpeg")
} 

output$finalImage <- renderImage({
   if(aws.s3::object_exists(key1, bucket_name) == TRUE){
      list(src = './images/image1.jpeg',
      contentType = 'image/jpeg',
      width = "200", height = "200",
      alt = "Screening")
   } 
}, deleteFile = FALSE)


Adding == TRUE is a bit like adding “is true” after every statement or question: it’s redundant and awkward. There’s basically never a need to use literal TRUE or FALSE in comparisons.

so to use s3_readusing() you need also a function capable of reading the image, so probably magick package.
